# jQuery Category Search with Remote Results and Caching

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use [JQuery Category Autocomplete (documented here)](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) to create a search box for my website that will search through results that are in another file located at "/search_basic.php" (file contents are listed below). I would like the results to be categorized and cached in browser for future. If no results are available, the user should also be notified. I am able to do each of these separately except for pulling the results from a remote file and caching. I can not figure out how to get my project working as a whole.

Here is the code I am using:

HTML5:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="search">Search: </label>
    <input id="search" />
    <p id="empty-message"></p>
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
.ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .8em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
    ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
    currentCategory = item.category;
    }
    that._renderItemData( ul, item );
    });
    }
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var cache ={};
        $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var term = request.term;
                if ( term in cache ) {
                    response( cache[ term ] );
                    return;
                }
                $.getJSON( "search_basic.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) { // Remote results file is located at search_basic.php
                    cache[ term ] = data;
                    response( data );
                });

                // If there are no results notify the user
                if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                    $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
                } else {
                    $("#empty-message").empty();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The following is the contents of search_basic.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

[
 { "label": "annhhx10", "category": "Products" },
 { "label": "annttop", "category": "Products" },
 { "label": "anders", "category": "People" },
 { "label": "andreas", "category": "People" }
]
```

Thank you in advance!

Update 1: I got jQuery UI's remote example to function on my server, however it is not easily modifiable to implement without the extra data that it returns. [A working example can be seen here](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/remote.html) and can be downloaded in their downloads section to view the remote json PHP file (sorry, I am unable to add more links with my SO reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the notification for an empty result should be handled in the `response` event:

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var cache ={};
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }
            $.getJSON( "search_basic.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) { // Remote results file is located at search_basic.php
                cache[ term ] = data;
                response( data );
            });   
        },
        response: function(event,ui){
            // If there are no results notify the user
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
            } else {
                $("#empty-message").empty();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried replacing with your code, however I still have the issue that nothing is displayed. According to my debugger, the browser is connecting to the search_basic.php file looking for results, however to the user nothing is displayed and it just seems that they are typing into a blank box. I have also tested this code on a live server to the same result. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/7mY3N/1/

Comment: @block14 to start debugging why don't you remove the custom _renderMenu function and make your `search_basic.php` return objects with the property "value" instead of "category", let's see if we can get the remote source working first

Comment: Good idea to simplify! I tried your suggestion to the same result mentioned in my previous comment. To simplify things even further, I copied the example on [jQuery UI's website](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/remote.html) however I am not able to download their search.php file to check their formatting. I think that maybe my remote file, search_basic.php, is not formatted correctly?

Comment: @block14 I think you're not producing any output in your json file, try using echo like this `header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo '[
 { "label": "annhhx10", "category": "Products" },
 { "label": "annttop", "category": "Products" },
 { "label": "anders", "category": "People" },
 { "label": "andreas", "category": "People" }
]';` but change "category" to "value" as the docs suggest that's the expected object structure

Comment: Changing echo to that format is not working either (to confirm, I changed "category" to "value"). On another note, I managed to figure out how to get jQuery UI's remote example to work: I found their [PHP file in this download](http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip). After correcting some of the script references and uploading it to a server it returned suggestions and data correctly (albeit with a few unrelated scripting errors). I am looking over this PHP file to see if it holds any clues to producing the correct output.